# Как вставить данные из DataGridView в Excel диапазон со сдвигом в C #

Tags: c#, excel

Не получается вставить данные из DataGridView в шаблон Excel. А именно не получается вставка со сдвигом вниз. Пожалуйста, предложите решение. Спасибо!

Вот шаблон:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
string path = "D:/Отчеты/Test.xlsx";
            string fileName = ((DataParametr)e.Argument).FileName;


            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("АО НК КТЖ");
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

            //app.Visible = false;

            int cellRowIndex = 1;
            int cellColumnIndex = 1;

            Excel.Range cellRange = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[dataGridView1.Rows.Count + 4, 2];
            cellRange.set_Value(Missing.Value, worksheet.get_Range("B11"));
            Excel.Range rowRange = cellRange.EntireRow;
            rowRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex+4, cellColumnIndex] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    cellColumnIndex++;
                }
                Excel.Range range = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex + 4, 1], worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex + 4, dataGridView1.Columns.Count-1]];
                FormattingExcelCells(range, "#CCCCFF", System.Drawing.Color.Black,false);
                range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                Excel.Borders border = range.Borders;
                border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                border.Weight = 2d;

                backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(cellRowIndex);
                cellColumnIndex = 1;
                cellRowIndex++;
            }

            workbook.SaveAs(fileName);
            app.Quit();
```

---

Comment: вставка в смысле ctrl+c / ctrl+v?

Comment: Кодом, используя библиотеку Interop

Comment: то есть вам нужна помощь с вашим кодом. Наверное имеет смысл ваш код добавить в вопрос.